# How many push notification quota per day for Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

Honestly i got a little headache of this, i tried to google it but there was no satisfied answer.

Might be some of you know about how many quota of push notification that given by `Blackberry Push Service` to the application per day ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As at this time there are two levels of Push supported, Essential and Plus.  The following page compares these two services:

https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/platform_services/push_features.html

Reviewing that page you will see that the only limit mentioned is the Plus Service, where you are allowed a maximum of 100,000 pushes before there is a fee chargeable.

Comment: How will i know all info about my blackberry push notification status ?    we registered it more than a years ago, so we didn't remember exactly. Is there any Blackberry Portal to login, so we can see all info about my apps push notification . Many Thanks :)